# Why the URL of image does not work in the css?

Tags: html, css, image, jsp, url

I have spent a whole day on this question and google many answers.

My login.css file is located on the:

```
WebContent/resources/css/login.css
```

My image file is located:

```
WebContent/resources/img/pencil.jpg
```

When I tried to add the image to the background of the body through this CSS:

```
body{
    background-image:url("../img/pencil.jpg") center center no-repeat;
}
```

It does not work!
 Also, I tried another method: I tried to add another image directly to my JSP page without through CSS.
My JSP locates in:

```
  WebContent/WEB-INF/views/login.jpg
```

My image locates in:

```
 WebContent/resources/img/calendar.png
```

the code in JSP is:

```
<img src="../../resources/img/calendar.png"/>
```

Both of them failed! Other things work fine, just the image fail! I do not why.

Here is the console:

```
[27 17:48:25,515 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'todo' processing GET request for [/ToDoList/login]
[27 17:48:25,527 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /login
[27 17:48:25,535 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView code.controller.LoginController.showLoginPage()]
[27 17:48:25,535 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'loginController'
[27 17:48:25,538 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/ToDoList/login] is: -1
[27 17:48:25,614 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'login'
[27 17:48:25,615 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'login'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'todo'
[27 17:48:25,615 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] view.JstlView - Added model object 'firstuser' of type [code.model.FirstUser] to request in view with name 'login'
[27 17:48:25,615 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] view.JstlView - Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.firstuser' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'login'
[27 17:48:25,625 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'login'
[27 17:48:25,799 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] beans.BeanUtils - No property editor [java.lang.StringEditor] found for type java.lang.String according to 'Editor' suffix convention
[27 17:48:25,812 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-2] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
[27 17:48:26,232 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'todo' processing GET request for [/ToDoList/resources/css/login.css]
[27 17:48:26,232 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-4] servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'todo' processing GET request for [/ToDoList/resources/js/login.js]
[27 17:48:26,232 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-5] servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'todo' processing GET request for [/ToDoList/resources/library/jquery-3.0.0.min.js]
[27 17:48:26,232 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /resources/css/login.css
[27 17:48:26,233 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-5] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /resources/library/jquery-3.0.0.min.js
[27 17:48:26,232 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-4] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /resources/js/login.js
[27 17:48:26,233 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-6] servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'todo' processing GET request for [/ToDoList/resources/library/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js]
[27 17:48:26,234 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-6] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /resources/library/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js
[27 17:48:26,235 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-5] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/resources/library/jquery-3.0.0.min.js]
[27 17:48:26,235 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/resources/css/login.css]
[27 17:48:26,237 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/resources/css/login.css] are [/resources/**]
[27 17:48:26,235 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-4] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/resources/js/login.js]
[27 17:48:26,237 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-6] annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/resources/library/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js]
[27 17:48:26,243 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-4] handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/resources/js/login.js] are [/resources/**]
[27 17:48:26,236 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-5] handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/resources/library/jquery-3.0.0.min.js] are [/resources/**]
[27 17:48:26,243 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-6] handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/resources/library/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js] are [/resources/**]
[27 17:48:26,247 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-4] handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/resources/js/login.js] are {}
[27 17:48:26,247 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/resources/css/login.css] are {}
[27 17:48:26,247 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-6] handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/resources/library/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js] are {}
[27 17:48:26,247 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-5] handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/resources/library/jquery-3.0.0.min.js] are {}
[27 17:48:26,253 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-5] handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/resources/library/jquery-3.0.0.min.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/resources/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@6f2e3841]]] and 1 interceptor
[27 17:48:26,253 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-4] handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/resources/js/login.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/resources/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@6f2e3841]]] and 1 interceptor
[27 17:48:26,253 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/resources/css/login.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/resources/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@6f2e3841]]] and 1 interceptor
[27 17:48:26,253 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-6] handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/resources/library/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/resources/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@6f2e3841]]] and 1 interceptor
[27 17:48:26,255 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-5] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/ToDoList/resources/library/jquery-3.0.0.min.js] is: -1
[27 17:48:26,255 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-4] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/ToDoList/resources/js/login.js] is: -1
[27 17:48:26,255 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/ToDoList/resources/css/login.css] is: -1
[27 17:48:26,255 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-6] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/ToDoList/resources/library/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js] is: -1
[27 17:48:26,263 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-6] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'todo': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
[27 17:48:26,264 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-6] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
[27 17:48:26,265 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-4] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'todo': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
[27 17:48:26,266 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-4] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
[27 17:48:26,270 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-5] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'todo': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
[27 17:48:26,270 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-5] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
[27 17:48:26,274 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'todo': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
[27 17:48:26,274 DEBUG] [http-nio-8080-exec-3] servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Can you post the console error?

Comment: sometimes if the extension is JPG or PNG and if you write jpg or png you get issues. Double check the extension and if it does not solve the problem then post the console error like Andrew said

Comment: Might be worth checking that you can load the image directly in the browser by typing the full URL to the image.  If it doesn't load then check file permissions and ownership on the image files and the containing directory.

Comment: @JohnSheridan I can load the image successfully using the full URL on my browser.

Comment: @AndrewRibeiro I updated it. But I did not see any error warning about the image in the console information.

Comment: @SaumilSoni I tried changing "pencil.jpg" to "pencil.JPG" in CSS, still not working.

Comment: give the absolute path like C://Documents/... and see if it will work or not

Answer (score 0):

Import the c tag on your jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Change the code on your jsp like below:

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/calendar.png"/>"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am pretty sure there are many methods to add the image in the JSP. Yesterday I also saw a method using the spring tag.

Answer (score 0):

After one day research, I figure it out with different friends' help! Thank you!

---

1. Firstly

   if you are using the Spring MVC like me, you should see this part. In the Spring MVC project, I tried to add the CSS and JS to the JSP.I put all the JSP into a file named "views" in the WEB-INF. I create a file named "resources" under the WebContent, same level with WEB-INF. In the "resources", all images are under the "img" file, so does CSS and JS in the "css" and "js".  In the spring-servlet.xml file(not web.xml file, maybe you have the different file name with me), add:`<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>`, which helps find the resources file. In the JSP pages which you want to contain the CSS and JS add: 

   `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/login.css"/>`

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/login.js"></script>`

Then you can link the JSP with CSS and JS successfully. Or you can use other tags to do this.

---

2. Secondly

   Next part is adding the image to the JSP page, you can do it in two ways. 
   Firstly, add the image through the JSP:

   `<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/img/calendar.png"/>`

   Secondly, add the image through the CSS: It is better to use the relative path. (A relative path is relative to the location of the CSS file not the JSP file)

   - ./ means current directory
   - ../ means parent directory
   - / means the root directory
   - ../../ means moving back two directories and start there

So in my situation, I should write

```
`background-image: url("../img/pencil.jpg");`
```

Another mistake I make is that: I should never add "no-repeat" at the back of the Background-image.